# jQuery UI only center of dragged element activates draggable trash

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, droppable

I am using "sortable" list and "droppable" trash. The problem is dragged element activate that trash only on the center. How can I spread that "activation area" to all the element?
[image]

[image]

And this is my jquery I used to do it:

```
$(".barbox").sortable({
    connectWith: '.connectedTrash, #droptaskdelete'
}).disableSelection();

$(".barbox").sortable({
    connectWith: '.connectedTrash, #droptaskdelete'
}).disableSelection();

$("#droptaskdelete").droppable({
    accept: ".connectedTrash .bar",
    hoverClass: "trash-active",
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
        ui.draggable.remove();
    }
});
```

Trash is working, the problem is with that "activation area". I want all dragged element to activate that trash.

Please for help.

Comment: Did you look at the API for the `tolerance` option? https://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-tolerance

Comment: Thank you, make normal post to let me give you "best answer" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the API for the `tolerance` option: https://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-tolerance